# Node.js with bluetooth and android

Tags: android, node.js, bluetooth

I need to create an application using node.js with bluetooth packages, through the android mobile i want to communicate my application, how can i create this one using node.js, with bluetooth packages. Bluetooth packages are always being listen to connect multiple devices(android)

Comment: so you want to an app right ?

Answer (score 0):

This module may be helpful (I have never used it though):

https://github.com/eelcocramer/node-bluetooth-serial-port

Comment: i tried with this, can able to communicate system to mobile, but i need mobile to system communication.

Comment: yes explored, but could not able to find out the solution. i need desktop machine should listen, and mobile device will connect through the node